# Xamarin iOS Geolocator Background Service Dying after about 30 mins

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, gps

I am currently using the Xamarin geolocation plugin found here:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin

To perform location services in an app I am building using Xamarin Forms (PCL).
I believe I have added in the relevant permission settings to allow for this.

The GPS works great while the app is active and locked (but with app in the foreground). However when the app is pushed to the background on iOS by clicking the "home" button, it still tracks the user and highlights the "App is Using Your Location" message as I would expect, however after a certain amount of time between 30-40 minutes, this message disappears, and the GPS appears to stop tracking the user until they bring the app back to the foreground.

Once the app has been brought to the foreground, it can be backgrounded once again for another 30-40 minutes to repeat the cycle.

I have ensured that the locator object allows background updates:

```
public static Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.IGeolocator locator;
locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.AllowsBackgroundUpdates = true;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 20;
```

A call to `.PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` shows that this is false (which I believe is the default).

**Edit**

I have the following keys to info.plist:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

And enabled background location updates:

[image]

[image]

However I have not enabled background fetching as Girish has in the answers, is this something I need to do?

Comment: Which permissions did you add and where?

Comment: Please see my edit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have enabled the background mode for location update.

[image]

Comment: I have enabled Location updates and background modes, I have not enabled background fetch or remote notifications, please see my edit